# Using a nested for-loop & asking user to enter values without spaces for a matrix

Tags: java, matrix, user-input, nested-loops, space

Is it possible to ask the user to enter values **WITHOUT SPACES** and then fill up the matrix character for character? I know that people have answered "how to ask the user to fill up a matrix" but my question is considering filling up a matrix without spaces.

```
char[][] rand = new char[3][3];
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        rand[i][j] = scanner.next().charAt(0);
    }
}
```

The problem with the code is that the user can enter with spaces

```
2 3 1
4 5 4
```

I want the user to be able to enter without spaces but including enter so

```
 231
 454
```

If printing output should be: [[2,3,1],[4,5,4]]

Comment: seeing as you only read one single char each time, how is this supposed to work?

Comment: using nextLine() instead of next will give you the entire line, but you'll need to change your logic in your loop.

Comment: @Stultuske im not sure what to change in the loop. But thx.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to know how to fill the array when entering the data without whitespaces? What should happen if whitespaces are input anyways?

Comment: @maloomeister yes! if the whitespaces are entered it should not work

Comment: I'm not gonna give you a full answer, but rather a hint. Set up your `Scanner` with `useDelimiter("")`. Then `scanner.next()` will read one char at a time. Combine this with `scanner.nextLine()` to empty the newline from the scanner buffer in your outer loop. Or alternatively, read each line as a whole as a `String` and manipulate the read string as needed manually.

Answer (score 2):

You could post an error, if a user enters a space and check it your Character with this static method of the Charakter Class, like:

```
Character.isWhitespace(characterToCheck)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let the user type spaces.

Whether your code works or not, it's another topic, however, you can:

- Trim spaces at the beginning and end of a string

```
String s = " 2 3 4 ";
String trimmed = s.trim(); // trimmed = "2 3 4"
```

- Replace spaces with empty chars to eliminate them

```
String s = " 2 3 4 ";
String replaced = s.replace(" ", ""); // replaced = "234"
```

- Split string straight into an array

```
String s = " 2 3 4 ";
String[] array = s.split(" ", -1); // array = [2, 3, 4]
```

As for why is that parameter -1? check here for more [on this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/#:%7E:text=limit%20%3E%200%20%E2%80%93,will%20be%20discarded.)

Comment: Thx! Should be useful tips in future problems.